# Updating database connection java

Tags: java, mysql, database, refresh

I have a question regarding updating the java program when something is inserted in a database.

The cenario is, is that i can insert a row in the used database, and then when i go to the next screen i can choose the last inserted row. The problem is, is that i have to restart the application to make the change visible so that i can choose the last inserted row. How do i refresh the the application without restarting it so that i can see the added rows (or deleted)?

thanks!

Comment: Have you recollected the data from the server then refreshed the GUI? What line gets the data from the server in your application? Also what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to add some properties to your database as follows:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(
                           ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                           ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

Now if your database if updated then your only have to refresh GUI to get the new values in your GUI.

here `Resultset.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` makes your database updatable so that any changes in your database will also be reflected in your application